# Caffe predicts same class regardless of image

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I [modified the MNIST example](https://github.com/jackbrucesimpson/caffe_tests/blob/master/lenet_train_test.prototxt) and when I train it with my 3 image classes it returns an accuracy of 91%. However, when I modify the [C++ example](https://github.com/jackbrucesimpson/caffe_tests/blob/master/classification.cpp) with a [deploy prototxt](https://github.com/jackbrucesimpson/caffe_tests/blob/master/deploy_arch.prototxt) file and [labels file](https://github.com/jackbrucesimpson/caffe_tests/blob/master/labels.txt), and try to test it on some images it returns a prediction of the second class (1 circle) with a probability of 1.0 no matter what image I give it - even if it's images that were used in the training set. I've tried a dozen images and it consistently just predicts the one class.

To clarify things, in the C++ example I modified I did scale the image to be predicted just like the images were scaled in the training stage:

```
img.convertTo(img, CV_32FC1);
img = img * 0.00390625;
```

If that was the right thing to do, then it makes me wonder if I've done something wrong with the output layers that calculate probability in my [deploy_arch.prototxt](https://github.com/jackbrucesimpson/caffe_tests/blob/master/deploy_arch.prototxt) file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have forgotten to scale the input image during classification time, as can be seen in line 11 of the train_test.prototxt file. You should probably multiply by that factor somewhere in your C++ code, or alternatively use a Caffe layer to scale the input (look into ELTWISE or POWER layers for this).

**EDIT:**

After a conversation in the comments, it turned out that the image mean was mistakenly being subtracted in the classification.cpp file whereas it was not being subtracted in the original training/testing pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for having a look, in the C++ example I modified I did include these lines of code on line 248 to try scale it, does this look correct?
    img.convertTo(img, CV_32FC1);
    img = img * 0.00390625;
If that was the right thing to do, then it makes me wonder if I've done something wrong with the output layers that calculate probability in my deploy_arch.prototxt file.

Comment: Actually, I found another error (I think). In Argmax (line 89), you are doing partial_sort, but that sorts according to *ascending* order, so the class you are getting is the *lowest* probability class instead of the highest probability.

Comment: Scratch that last comment. I see you have a different PairCompare class.

Comment: To be honest the only parts that I changed from the Caffe C++ example were the two lines to scale my images in the code, so that's why I'm starting to suspect that the error might be creeping in with my prototxt file I use with the trained Caffe model.

Comment: Hmm. I see. Can you try to output the cv::Mat before Preprocess to verify that it is indeed within the correct range (which should ideally be [0,1])?

Comment: Just ran it, this was an example of the output:
0.04296875, 0.046875, 0.0390625, 0.0859375, 0.07421875, 0.07421875
So it looks like the scaling part is working, I'm just finding the prediction probability of 1.0 for circle that never changes really weird.

Comment: Okay can you also output input_channels at the end of Preprocess (at line 158), and see if those are the same as the values in img? Otherwise I can't really find anything hugely different between your implementation and caffe's.

Comment: input_channels stored one Mat object (which makes sense as my image was grayscale). The first few values were [-64.031227, -64.027321, -64.035133, -63.988258, -63.999977, -63.999977, -64.019508, -64.023415, -63.999977, -64.003883...

The grayscale Mat img  had those values that I wrote before: [0.04296875, 0.046875, 0.0390625, 0.0859375, 0.07421875, 0.07421875, 0.0546875...

That's really weird, I don't understand why the C++ program would change the values and why it works when I run it with their example data but not with mine.

Comment: Ah I see. I think this is because the code is subtracting the mean from the mean.binaryproto file. You shouldn't be doing that since you didn't have any mean subtraction in the original train_test.prototxt. Try changing line 219 to `cv::split(sample_resized, *input_channels);` and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: That fixed it!! Just ran a test and it's working perfectly now, thank-you so, so so much!!!!

Comment: It says I have to wait 20 hours to award the bounty so I'll bookmark the page but please remind me if I haven't assigned the bounty by tomorrow!

Answer (score 1):

Are your train classes balanced?
You may get to a stacked network on a prediction of one major class.
In order to find the issue I suggest to output the train prediction during training compared to predictions with the forward example on same train images from a different class.

Comment: My three classes are being trained with 7671 (circle), 7278 (rectangle) 2113 (blank) images. I could understand if it was having trouble with the blank tag images but the circles and rectangles are pretty similar in regards to the number of training files. What should I add to my train/test prototxt file (https://github.com/jackbrucesimpson/caffe_tests/blob/master/lenet_train_test.prototxt) to get it to output the probabilities?